# how to discard sms using webworks in blackberry

Tags: cordova, sms, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I am developing an application using webworks api for blackberry OS 5.

my application is listening to received SMSs and detect specific messages from a specicfic numbers then extract some information of it.
my problem is to delete this message from inbox of mobile !

how to discard an sms from blackberry mobile inbox ?

Answer (score 1):

In BlackBerry OS 7.1 and lower there is no API for a third party application to delete SMS messages from the user's inbox or block messages from appearing there.

The sender of the SMS message can craft it in a way to prevent it from being shown in the user's inbox.  For more information on that see [Use SMS to notify an application](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Use-SMS-to-notify-an-application/ta-p/444965).